# Jenkins hangs on Mac slave when cloning from Gitlab instance

Tags: macos, git, ssh, jenkins, gitlab

We are trying to build an iOS app through a Jenkins job, but we are unable to clone the repository from our Gitlab instance. As of now, Jenkins hangs (until the 10 minute timeout) when git fetches the references.

Below is the Jenkins output:

```
Started by user <USER>
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Mac_Slave in workspace /Users/<MAC USER>/Documents/Jenkins/workspace/<REPO>
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@<GITLAB>:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git
Fetching upstream changes from git@<GITLAB>:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git
 > git --version
using GIT_SSH to set credentials <MAC SLAVE>
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@<GITLAB>:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@<GITLAB>:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@<GITLAB>:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:623)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:855)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:880)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1251)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:605)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@<GITLAB>:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1307)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1169)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:257)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We have added the Mac's SSH public key as the deploy key for the repository and we used the Mac's SSH private key as the credentials, but for some reason, it won't work. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Looking at the logs on the Mac slave, I noticed that it prompts the user to "Enter passphrase for key `'/var/folders/92/<RANDOM STRING OF CHARACTERS>/T/ssh<RANDOM STRING OF NUMBERS>key':"` and if I manually enter the passphrase for the SSH key, it works. However this solution isn't ideal for an automated build system.

Digging further, if I actually go to the `'/var/folders/92/<RANDOM STRING>/T/'` folder, I see a few files. When the Mac slave is prompted for the passphrase, a `ssh<RANDOM NUMBERS>key` file, a `ssh<DIFF RANDOM NUMBERS>.sh` file, and a `pass<OTHER DIFF RANDOM NUMBERS>.sh` file appear. The `ssh<...>key` file contains the SSH private key, the `ssh<...>.sh` file contains an ssh command using that private key, and the `pass<...>.sh` file contains a command to echo the SSH passphrase.

Comment: What happens if you run the same git fetch command from the command line, using the same credentials that Jenkins uses ?

Comment: It works just fine. No issues cloning the repository by hand using the Mac slave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the SSH key to the Mac's keychain or remove the password in the SSH key. In order to add to the keychain run `ssh-add <SSH PRIVATE KEY FILE>` on the Mac (you might also need to enable the ssh-agent doing `eval $(ssh-agent)`).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your Jenkins slave process runs with a different user than the one you used to run git from command line. If that is the case  - you'll need to approve the initial host key verification for that user before you can run git in Jenkins.
(you know - that message you get when connecting with ssh for the first time:

```
The authenticity of host '111.11.11.11' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3f:1b:f4:bd:c5:aa:c1:1f:bf:4e:2e:cf:53:fa:d8:59.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

)

Comment: Is there any way to see which user is being used from Jenkins? Because in the Mac's .ssh/known_hosts file is a reference to the Gitlab repository.

Comment: `echo $USER` in a jenkins Job
or if you're using the envinject plugin (recommended!) you have the 'Environment Varables' link on the build page.

Comment: The user is correct. I just edited the original post with more stuff I have figured out.